# How to Export RCP application through command line

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am trying to automate the build process of RCP application. Currenty I'm having "ApplicationName.product" file im my RCP project. With the help of the file am exporting product. But I want to export the product through command line.

anyone have any idea on this?????

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tycho http://eclipse.org/tycho/  to manage your RCP projects by using Apache Maven, then you can test & build your RCP application from build automation system or command line by calling something like `mvn package`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Maven: the old-fashioned way to build RCP products is the ant-based [PDE build](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/pde-build/). A good description how to set up your own build is [Markus Barchfeld's article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-Automation/automation.html) - it's quite old, but PDE build hasn't changed much since Eclipse 3.0.